# Issues with Scanner Preventing System.out from Printing

Tags: java

I'm getting an error where I'm trying to take input as a string, but whenever I use Scanner's nextLine feature, it causes the next line - or several lines - of System.out.print or println not to show up at all until  about 3 random strings. I'm working on a homework assignment for my Computer Science class that's really strict about cheating, so for simplicity's sake I'm going to upload a completely irrelevant yet similar example that demonstrates my issue.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String floor = reader.nextLine();

        if(floor.equals("F")){
            String floorName = "";
            System.out.print("Enter floorname:");
            floorName = reader.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm also using IntelliJ Idea as an IDE and Gradle for the compiler, I'm not quite sure if that'd be something that'd affect this but I figured it's relevant information.

For reference, this outputs:

F (user inputs F)

f (user inputs whatever)

Enter floorname: (this pops in late)

Comment: That doesn't happen for me. "Enter floorname:" shows up immediately after I inputted "F" and pressed enter.

Comment: After `System.out.print("Enter floorname:");` add `System.out.flush()` . Buffering of the output seems to be the issue.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Your "similar example" does not show the issue you described. Add the actual source code you have which have the problem you described to your question. Also keep in mind that you have to press the "Enter" key for reading a line. Until then your code will wait for the `nextLine()` method to finish.

Comment: @Progman It might not on your IDE but it does in mine.

Comment: @Ryotsu Tried System.out.flush(), still the same result.

Comment: @Brenbold you should compile and run it using the command line, your ide console seems to be buffering outputs, are you by any chance using Gradle?